# How to select multiple dates into one textbox?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, calendar, asp.net-4.5

I want select multiple dates into one `TextBox` using asp `CalendarExtender`. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with Asp.Net CalendarExtender. I recommend you to use a jquery-based calendar. Here is a good one to solve your problem: http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can add dates by comma separated by jquery

You can check form below two links:
www.jsfiddle.net/3t4j9/

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/49896/select-multiple-dates-in-jquery-date-picker.aspx

Comment: Please include the relevant code from the link in your answer. Links can go bad over time and future searchers of this question may not find their answer.